# Apache Felix 6.0.1: BundleException on init

Tags: java, osgi, apache-felix

With Apache Felix 6.0.1 I'm getting the following error when initializing the OSGi framework:

```
ERROR: Error parsing system bundle statement.
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exported package names cannot be zero length.
at org.apache.felix.framework.util.manifestparser.ManifestParser.normalizeExportClauses(ManifestParser.java:865)
at org.apache.felix.framework.util.manifestparser.ManifestParser.<init>(ManifestParser.java:217)
at org.apache.felix.framework.ExtensionManager$ExtensionManagerRevision.update(ExtensionManager.java:977)
at org.apache.felix.framework.ExtensionManager$ExtensionManagerRevision.access$000(ExtensionManager.java:885)
at org.apache.felix.framework.ExtensionManager.updateRevision(ExtensionManager.java:378)
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.init(Felix.java:744)
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.init(Felix.java:637)
```

I didn't get this error with Apache Felix 5.x

And I couldn't find any JAR which has an empty package names declaration except my executable JAR, which is not an OSGi bundle at all.

Why do I get this error?

**Update**

The issue seems to be with the bundle goal of the Maven Bundle Plugin v4.1.0

In one startup JAR with bundle packaging I have:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <extensions>true</extensions>  
            <configuration>
                <versions>
                    <module.b.osgi.version.clean>${project.version}</module.b.osgi.version.clean>
                </versions>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>cleanVersions</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>     
        </plugin>
```

In a properties file with resource filtering set to true I have:

```
org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra=${module-b.packages}

module-b.packages=${module-a.packages}, \
org.mymodule.b;version="${module.b.osgi.version.clean}", \
${foo-${foo.specification.version}}
```

In the generated target/classes directory I have as expected:

```
org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra=${module-b.packages}

module-b.packages=${module-a.packages}, \
org.mymodule.b;version="0.14.0.SNAPSHOT",  \
${foo-${foo.specification.version}}
```

But in the JAR it then suddenly looks like this:

```
org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra=${module-b.packages}

module-b.packages=${module-a.packages}, \
org.mymodule.b;version="0.14.0.SNAPSHOT", \
```

Somehow `${foo-${foo.specification.version}}` got stripped to empty string!

**Update 2**

As this happens in the startup code, my current work-around is to change the packaging type back to jar. The OSGi clean version still gets substituted, but the Manifest file doesn't contain any OSGi entries anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a regression bug in the Maven Bundle Plugin.

I've filed an issue here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FELIX-5980